# How to fix StreamlitAPIException: ("Expected bytes, got a 'int' object", 'Conversion failed for column FG% with type object')

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

**Error:**

```
StreamlitAPIException: ("Expected bytes, got a 'int' object", 'Conversion failed for column FG% with type object')
```

**Error Traceback**

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\ASUS\streamlit_freecodecamp-main\app_3_eda_basketball\basketball_app.py", line 44, in <module>
    st.dataframe(df_selected_team)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 31):

It’s a bug that came with `streamlit 0.85.0`. [`pyarrow`](https://blog.streamlit.io/all-in-on-apache-arrow/) has an issue with `numpy.dtype` values (which df.dtypes returns).

The [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-14087) has been filed and hopefully will be taken care of soon.

A possible workaround is to convert DataFrame cells to strings with `df.astype(str)`

In your case

```
test = df_selected_team.astype(str)
st.dataframe(test)
```

or

downgrade your streamlit version to `0.84`

or

A preferable solution for this is to use the old dataframe serializer by setting this in your .streamlit/config.toml file:

```
[global]
dataFrameSerialization = "legacy"
```

This allows you to continue upgrading to the latest version of Streamlit.

Follow this [thread](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/after-upgrade-to-the-latest-version-now-this-error-id-showing-up-arrowinvalid/15794/7) for more updates

Comment: Great! I used the `"legacy"` option, and it works just fine. Every problem has a solution here already, marvellous!

Comment: Using 'legacy' serializer will negate the [benefits](https://blog.streamlit.io/all-in-on-apache-arrow/) from the new Arrow based data frame serializer if your data frame size is large. So suggest using str conversion before display as interim.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Then I downgraded my streamlit version to make it work, currently, I'm running streamlit 0.75.