# How to concat many uploaded csv files in one DataFrame in Streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I made program that takes csv files and count mean values. I try to make interface in streamlit.
I try to use solution from my program

```
data = st.file_uploader("Wybierz pliki CSV:",type = 'csv', accept_multiple_files=True)
for file in data:
   Table = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',')
   DF1 = pd.DataFrame(Table)
   DFL = pd.concat([DFL,DF1], sort=False)
```

When i try to print this using `st.dataframe(DFL)`
I get this error:

StreamlitAPIException: ("Could not convert '06028001018' with type str: tried to convert to int64", 'Conversion failed for column LPROS1 with type object')

Anyone know how to concat it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> StreamlitAPIException: ("Could not convert '06028001018' with type str: tried to convert to int64", 'Conversion failed for column LPROS1 with type object')

It’s a bug that came with **streamlit** 0.85.0. `pyarrow` has an issue with `numpy.dtype` values (which `df.dtypes` returns).

As a workaround you can add the below lines to your code

```
DF2 = DFL.astype(str)
st.dataframe(DFL2)
```

or try other suggested workaround from here

[How to fix StreamlitAPIException: ("Expected bytes, got a 'int' object", 'Conversion failed for column FG% with type object')](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69581451/14045537)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
data = st.file_uploader("Wybierz pliki CSV:",type = 'csv', 
accept_multiple_files=True)
Table = []
for file in data:
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
         Table.append(pd.read_csv(file)

df = pd.concat(Table, sort=False)
```

Comment: I try your code but i get the same error.

Comment: Try without .endswith(".csv")

Comment: I tryed but i get error :StreamlitAPIException: ("Could not convert '06028001018' with type str: tried to convert to int64", 'Conversion failed for column LPROS1 with type object'). It is the same error as at the begining.

Answer (score 0):

Recheck your error message.

```
StreamlitAPIException: ("Could not convert '06028001018' with type str: tried to convert to int64", 'Conversion failed for column LPROS1 with type object')
```

It is about the data type in column LPROS1.

Comment: Ok but I don't convert this column, I don't know why streamlit try to convert it.  I just want to make one big DF.