# The streamlit does not refresh the dataframe on the localhost

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I am New in pandas and streamlit , What I am trying is to filter such a dataframe using streamlit selectbox
but unfortunately everything is going well except that when changing the filter value it does not reflect on the shown table

[image]
as you could see the name in the filter does not update the table

here is the code I have used:

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import datetime
import streamlit as st
# import plotly_express as px

# to refer to the file
# change the current directory
currentDir = os.chdir('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\lists');

files=os.listdir(currentDir)
columns=['Name','status','memorize-from-surah','memorize-from-ayah','memorize-to-surah','memorize-to-ayah','memorization-grade','words-meaning-grade','revision-from-surah','revision-from-ayah','revision-to-surah','revision-to-ayah','revision-grade']


folderDF=pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:

    # get the file name without extension for the sheikh name
    sheikh=os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    sheetDF=pd.DataFrame()

    workbook = pd.ExcelFile(f'C:\\users\\user\\Desktop\\lists\\{file}')

    sheets_numbers = len(workbook.sheet_names)
    print(sheets_numbers)
    for i in range(1, sheets_numbers-1):
        # print(workbook.sheet_by_index(i).name)
        current_sheet = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name=i,header=None,index_col=1)
        date= current_sheet.iloc[6, 10]
        # for j in range(7,current_sheet.nrows):
        #     if current_sheet.cell(j,3).value=="غاب" or current_sheet.cell(j,3).value=="عذر":
        #        for k in range(4,current_sheet.ncols):
        #            current_sheet.cell(j,k).value=""




        sheets=pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name=i,skiprows=11,header=None,index_col=1)


        # df = pd.DataFrame(sheets.iloc[:,1:], index=index)
        #remove the first col
        df=pd.DataFrame(sheets.iloc[:,1:])

        #remove empty rows
        df=df[df.iloc[:,0].notna()]
        #rename the columns

        df.columns = columns

        #get the nrows
        nrows= len(df.index)
        sheikhCol=pd.Series(nrows*sheikh)
        dateCol=pd.Series(nrows*date)
        halkaCol=pd.Series(nrows*i)

        # df.insert(1,"sheikh",sheikhCol)
        df.insert(1,"halka",halkaCol)
        df.insert(2,"sheikh",sheikhCol)
        df.insert(3,"date",dateCol)
        df["sheikh"]=sheikh
        df['date']=date
        df['halka']=i
        if i == 1:
            sheetDF=pd.DataFrame(df)
            datatoexcel = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\users\\user\\Desktop\\dataOut.xlsx')
            sheetDF.to_excel(datatoexcel)
            datatoexcel.save()

        else:
            sheetDF = pd.concat([sheetDF, df], axis=0)

    folderDF=pd.concat([folderDF,sheetDF],axis=0)



    datatoexcel=pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\users\\user\\Desktop\\dataOut.xlsx')
    folderDF.to_excel(datatoexcel)
    datatoexcel.save()

#

# setting up the streamlit page
st.set_page_config(page_title='makraa reports',layout='wide')




# make filteration
#
st.sidebar.header("make filtration criteria")
nameFilter= folderDF['Name'].unique()
halkaFilter= folderDF['halka'].unique()
sheikhFilter= folderDF['sheikh'].unique()


student_choice= st.sidebar.selectbox("select the student Name",nameFilter)
halka_choice= st.sidebar.selectbox("select the halka Number",halkaFilter)
sheikh_choice= st.sidebar.selectbox("select the sheikh Number",sheikhFilter)
# student_choice2= st.sidebar.multiselect("select the student Name",options=nameFilter,default=nameFilter)

# filteredDf=folderDF[folderDF["Name"]== student_choice]
filteredDf = folderDF[(folderDF["Name"] == student_choice) & (folderDF["halka"] == halka_choice)]
# filteredDf=folderDF.query('Name==@student_choice')
st.write(filteredDf)
```

note `st.dataframe(filteredDf)` does not make any difference

the streamlit version I used is 0.75 , since the recent version gave me the StreamlitAPIException like that [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69578431/how-to-fix-streamlitapiexception-expected-bytes-got-a-int-object-conver)

could you give a hand in this

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code with example data.

#### Code

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd


data = {
    'Name': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'halka': [1, 2, 3]
}


st.set_page_config(page_title='makraa reports',layout='wide')

folderDF = pd.DataFrame(data)


# make filteration
#
st.sidebar.header("make filtration criteria")
nameFilter = folderDF['Name'].unique()
halkaFilter = folderDF['halka'].unique()
# sheikhFilter = folderDF['sheikh'].unique()


student_choice = st.sidebar.selectbox("select the student Name", nameFilter)
halka_choice = st.sidebar.selectbox("select the halka Number", halkaFilter)
# sheikh_choice= st.sidebar.selectbox("select the sheikh Number",sheikhFilter)
# student_choice2= st.sidebar.multiselect("select the student Name",options=nameFilter,default=nameFilter)

filteredDf = folderDF[(folderDF["Name"] == student_choice) & (folderDF["halka"] == halka_choice)]
# filteredDf = filteredDf[filteredDf["halka"] == halkaFilter]

st.write(filteredDf)
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: still not working ,here is the complete code , I read the dataframe form an excel , I edit it in the main post